# Retrieving new oracle table records on insert to process in Java client application

Tags: java, plsql, spring-jdbc, spring-jms, oracle19c

I am trying to retrieve the new inserts from a table in my java client application (Spring JMS), to do some processing and send them to a message broker. I do not have access to any CDC tool like Goldengate. I only need the new inserts and not the updates or deletes. I am having difficulty finding a way to do this. Is there a way to do this? I read that there is an option to do these with triggers, but will it have a high throughput on the db, because this table gets a lot of inserts in a day (approximately around 50K records inserted in a day).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50,000 rows per day is actually rather a low volume. Some data warehouse tables get 50 million rows a day. So an insert trigger is unlikely to make any appreciable difference on the loading job. Add a date column (e.g. LOAD_DATE) and have a before insert trigger assign :new.LOAD_DATE := SYSDATE.

That being said, if you wanted to avoid a trigger, you can modify the loading job itself to load such a date a column with SYSDATE.

With either method, your retrieval is then simple: each day as you retrieve records, record the maximum LOAD_DATE value you retrieved. The next day, pull only records with a LOAD_DATE >= that value.

Comment: What if I want to get the data as soon as it is inserted instead having to pull it each day? An example would help me. Thx for your answer.

Comment: You can use the same logic I outlined in my answer, but retrieve every hour, or every minute, or however frequently you want. The same date logic would work, as dates carry precision to the second.